# how can i improve these functions to bind bitmaps on recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, bitmap, base64

I have a set of two functions that i use to bind images to a recyclerview, one is for converting a string (base64) to a bitmap, the other function is to round the corners of said image.

```
 //convert string to bitmap
    fun stringToBitMap( encodedString: String): Bitmap? {
        println("string to bitmap is being called")
        return try {
            val encodeByte: ByteArray = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT)
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.size)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Failed to convert string to bitmap")
            e.message
            null
        }
    }
    
    //round corners
    fun getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, pixels: Int): Bitmap {
        println("get rounded corners is being called")
        val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(output)
        val color = -0xbdbdbe
        val paint = Paint()
        val rect = Rect(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        val rectF = RectF(rect)
        val roundPx = pixels.toFloat()
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
        paint.color = color
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint)
        paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint)
        return output
    }
```

and i anotate my final function with BindingAdapter, then i call the function from the xml file

```
 @BindingAdapter("poster")
    fun image (view: ImageView, image: String) {
        return view.setImageBitmap(stringToBitMap(image)?.let { getRoundedCornerBitmap(it, 10) })
    }
```

it works, but the performance is poor in some devices, im debbugin my app in a low resource phone (samsung SM-J106B) and the spikes of cpu usage are 35% when scrolling fast(my images are not high res, only 400x400), also the recyclerview keeps calling these functions and it makes the scrolling kinda sluggish. So the question is, how can i improve my functions?

pd: im a complete newbie :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the glide like this:

```
    fun poster(view: ImageView, image: String) {
    val imageByteArray: ByteArray = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val round = RequestOptions
        .bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(14))

    Glide.with(view)
        .load(imageByteArray)
        .apply(round)
        .into(view)
}
```

performance is better now :D